# JSON.parse Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Tags: javascript, json

I have this `JSON` :

```
var data =  [{
    "ID":1,"Name":"Test",
    "subitem": [
        {"idenID":1,"Code":"254630"},
        {"idenID":2,"Code":"4566"},
        {"idenID":3,"Code":"4566"}
    ]
}];

console.log(JSON.parse(data)); //Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
```

How to de-serialize `data` to javascript object.

Comment: What you have here are [JavaScript literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Literals). Their syntax is precisely where JSON got its. But, within JavaScript code, JSON will always be formatted data stored within a `String`, which is the data type that `JSON.parse()` expects.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It already is an object ... of type `Array`. To access the `Object`:

```
var foo = data[0];

alert(foo.ID);
```

[`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) takes a `String` and parses it into an equivalent JavaScript value.

Answer (score 2):

This is usable in Javascript. You need to parse JSON when your data is in String format and you get it from server side.

The purpose of JSON.parse is to convert to Javascipt Object Notation to use it. For example,

```
var str = "{"a":1,"b":2}";
var obj = JSON.parse(str); //obj = {a:1, b:2}
```

Reference [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Technically, JSON.parse converts *from* JavaScript Object Notation to a native object.

Comment: @Colin Can you explain little more. According to MDN, "Parse a string as JSON, optionally transforming the value produced by parsing." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: @Khan: I think what he's saying is that `JSON.parse` parses a string containing JSON into a JavaScript object, and that only the former is called JSON, not the latter.

Comment: thank you @icktoofay Now it makes sense, JS object Notation in string is converted to JS object. (still a long way to learn English Language)

Comment: @icktoofay: Thanks for clarifying :) I hope that's at least somewhat helpful, KhanSharp.